# Selenium: element is not attached to the page document restaurant get free food script

Tags: python, selenium

Trying to make a free food finder but get unknown error

I'm trying to make this code to get every free product in this food delivery restaurant
I expect it to iterate through this 'hbaEIe.sc-5674cfe4-2' elements, that look like this:
[Restaurant div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMoZb.png)

```
url = 'https://www.rappi.com.ar/restaurantes'

for restaurant in all_restaurant:
    link = restaurant.get_attribute("href")
    full_link = base_url + link
    name = restaurant.get_attribute("aria-label")

    # open tab
    driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't')

    # Load a page
    driver.get(full_link)

    getFreeStuff(name, full_link)

    # close the tab
    driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'w')

    print(name)
```

Then, for each restaurant i want to iterate through all the product list and get the price, comparing it to 0.

```
def getFreeStuff(restaurant, link):
    time.sleep(1)
    prices = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "css-kowr8")
    names = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "css-puxjan")
    for i in range(0, len(prices)):
        price = prices[i]
        if price == "$ 0,00":
            restaurants.append(restaurant)
            links.append(link)
            products.append(names[i])
    return 0
```

But when i run it it gives me the following error:

```
BOULEVARD HONORIO
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Web Scraping\practica2\main.py", line 39, in <module>
    link = restaurant.get_attribute("href")
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Web Scraping\practica1\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 155, in get_attribute
    attribute_value = self.parent.execute_script(...

selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=107.0.5304.107)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x00A3ACD3+2075859]
    Ordinal0 [0x009CEE61+1633889]
        ...
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x771A7B8E+238]


Process finished with exit code 1
```

I've tried many things, but i don't know how to proceed

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the page is refreshed but you keep the old reference in your varibale. Try rediscovering element in the dom after refresh.

Comment: I don't get in what part that happens

Comment: If you store the result from driver.findElement to a variable and then you refresh the page for some reason and then you try to access the value of the variable again it will give you stale element exception

Comment: But i don't refresh the page

Comment: Something is refreshing the dom for sure.

Comment: Maybe when i 'access' the restaurant pages, is there a way to do it without the driver.get? So the previous site keeps loaded

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your attempt to open the individual restaurant link in a new tab is not successful.  As a result you are no longer on the main page when iterating to the second item in the list.  As you are only taking the name and link for each restaurant from the main page I would suggest it is best to store this data and then simply step through all of the restaurant pages adding free items (sadly there don't seem to be any!) to the restaurant objects:

```
all_restaurant = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[@class='sc-5674cfe4-2 hbaEIe']")
for restaurant in all_restaurant:
    link = restaurant.get_attribute("href")
    name = restaurant.get_attribute("aria-label")
    restaurants.append({"name":name, "link":link})
for restaurant in restaurants:
    # Load a page
    driver.get(restaurant["link"])
    products = getFreeStuff(driver, name, link)
    if len(products) > 0:
        restaurant["products"] = products 

def getFreeStuff(driver):
    time.sleep(1)
    products = []
    prices = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "css-kowr8")
    names = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "css-puxjan")
    for i in range(0, len(prices)):
        price = prices[i]
        if price == "$ 0,00":
            products.append(names[i])
    return products
```

Comment: Oh, that's nice. Thanks, i'll try it and let you know